# How can I connect a subquery without filters to a query with filters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query similar to the simplified one below.

```
SELECT
  Users.ID,
  Registrations.Timestamp
FROM
  Users,
  Registrations
WHERE
  Users.ID = Registrations.UserID AND
  Registrations.Date >= '2020-02-27'
ORDER BY
  Users.ID,
  Registrations.Timestamp;
```

I want to calculate a third column named `Type` with the values `entry` and `departure` like the following desired result:

```
ID  | Timestamp           | Type
----+---------------------|----------
1   | 2020-02-27 05:43:24 | entry
1   | 2020-02-27 13:48:47 | departure
1   | 2020-02-28 05:44:38 | entry
1   | 2020-02-28 13:50:11 | departure
2   | 2020-02-27 13:44:41 | entry
2   | 2020-02-27 21:47:54 | departure
2   | 2020-02-28 13:40:16 | entry
2   | 2020-02-28 21:52:57 | departure
3   | 2020-02-27 05:46:20 | departure
3   | 2020-02-28 21:44:05 | entry
3   | 2020-02-28 05:47:18 | departure
```

The way it calculates it is by counting the amount of registrations up to that one (without the `Date` filter). If the resulting count number is odd then consider it an `entry` else if it's even a `departure`.

In the example the user number 3 starts as `departure` because even though it is the first registration (odd number), without the `Date` filter it's an even number.

I have tried using a subquery but can't figure out how to count only up to the `Timestamp`, not all of them.

```
SELECT
  Users.ID,
  Registrations.Timestamp,
  CASE WHEN
    (
      SELECT
        COUNT(Registrations.Timestamp)
      FROM
        Registrations
      WHERE
        Registrations.UserID = OuterUsers.ID AND
        Registrations.Timestamp <= OuterRegistrations.Timestamp
    ) % 2 = 0 THEN
    'departure'
  ELSE
    'entry'
  END AS Type
FROM
  Users,
  Registrations
WHERE
  Users.ID = Registrations.Timestamp.UserID AND
  Registrations.Date >= '2020-02-27'
ORDER BY
  Users.ID,
  Registrations.Timestamp;
```

This sort of problem is likely not unique but I can't figure out even one solution to it from searching through some similar questions.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` first and then filter.  Also use to learn proper,explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax:

```
Select u.*, r.*,
       (case when seqnum % 2 = 1  then 'entry' else 'departure' end) as type
FROM users u JOIN
     (SELECT r.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY Date) as seqnum
      FROM Registrations r
     ) r
     ON u.ID = r.Timestamp.UserID
WHERE r.Date >= '2020-02-27'
ORDER BY u.ID, r.Timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a rank/row number ordered by timestamp and use these values to determine departure and entry instead

```
Select *, case when row_num % 2 = 0  then 'departure' else 'entry' end as type
FROM
(SELECT
    Users.ID,
     row_number() over (partition by ID order by timestamp) as row_num
        FROM
          Users,
          Registrations
        WHERE
          Users.ID = Registrations.Timestamp.UserID AND
          Registrations.Date >= '2020-02-27'
        ORDER BY
          Users.ID,
          Registrations.Timestamp) a;
```